# Regex in splunk - starting with number and has comma in between

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying write a regex to extract the number so that I can calculate the sum.
Below is the event:

```
abre0001.pxm:  55 records processed as of 2022-07-28 00:55:51.829407 

abre0001.pxm:  23,555 records processed as of 2022-07-28 00:55:51.829407 

abcd0001.pxm:  23,45,555 records processed as of 2022-07-28 00:55:52.543170
```

I want to extract the fields 55, 23,555, and 23,45,555 from each event and calculate the sum. However, I am unable to extract the number with a comma in it. I am able to get just the entries with only digits. Below is the regex used.

```
index="" source="" sourcetype="r"  "ab*0001.pxm" 
| rex field=_raw "pxm:\s+(?<value>/d+)/s" 
| convert rmcomma(value) 
| stats sum(value) as total_entries
```

The value field is unable to extract the number having a comma. It only extracts 55 rest of the entries are blank. Not sure what explicitly we need to give here.

Comment: @RichaG can you pls help here

Comment: @warren can u help here

Comment: If you can get the number out with the comma's you can use the replace command
| eval n=replace(n,",","")

where n is the field you extracted with the digits and commas

Comment: Rex for capture: "pxm:\s+(?<value>[\d,]+)\s"     
d, and s are escaped and added "," to group that can be in the named capture group "values"

Comment: Oh nice I've just look up the convert command,  Didn't know about it, learnt something new :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
| rex field=_raw "pxm:\s+(?<value>[\d,]+)\s"
| eval value=replace(value,",","")
```

d, and s are escaped and added "," to group that can be in the named capture group "value"

You then need to remove any commas, since they're not numerical